# How to COUNT best Player in range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to count best players in range, however if two players They have the same score in one column excel return message is: Same Result.

[image]

Comment: How is the best player determined? I mean, Djokovic just won right :), but in all seriousness, where's the score column in your screenshot?

Comment: @BigBen How is the best player determined? I count manually Rooger Federer 8,Rafael Nadal 2, Novak Djokovic 5, Andy murray 2 best number is 8 (Roger federer)

Comment: Ahhhh - your question is confusing then. It was unclear what you meant by "They have the same score in one column."

Comment: Based on the detail you gave in the comments, all you need is to use COUNTIF(), but if you want more constraints then COUNTIFS()

Comment: @BigBen "They have the same score in one column." So they have the same number of wins.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ARRAY Formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A18,MODE(MATCH(A2:A18,A2:A18,0)))
```

The formula returns the player that appear more time on the list. Remember to confirm the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER as is an array formula so you get the brackets:

```
{=INDEX(A2:A18,MODE(MATCH(A2:A18,A2:A18,0)))}
```

If there are two players with the same amount of wins, the formula will show the first to appear on the list.

Comment: This Great formula, I'm trying to change formula but in vain: {=INDEX(A2:A18,MODE(IF(EXACT(MATCH(A2:A18,A2:A18,0)),"Same Result","")))}

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my way to find the best player.
Firstly, I calculate the total champion won by each player using =COUNTIF(A:A,B3). 
Then, I display the player name with =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0),2))

Can anyone think of any quicker way to find the best player?

Comment: In which cell to apply formula =COUNTIF(A:A,B3)
I have a error #N/A for this formula: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0),2))

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena   You can apply =COUNTIF(A:A,B3) in wherever cell you like. The purpose of this formula is to count the number of times each player won the champion. If you have #N/A error for the second formula, please try to check if the range in MAX and MATCH function is the range of players.